# Can't push the contents of 'app' folder from Android Studio into github

Tags: android, github

[image]

[image]

I already tried checking into .gitignore file. but app/ folder is not present. Can somebody give me solution on how to add contents of app folder into github. I don't know what I am doing wrong?
Its showing me this error:

> modified:   app (modified content, untracked content)
>
> modified:   build (modified content, untracked content)

Comment: I am getting the message of untracked files inside folder 'app'.

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to first add the contents of app folder

**git add app**

2.Then commit

**git commit**

3.And finally push

**git push origin master** 
(or according to your branch and remote setup)

Comment: Hi Nishant , Thanks for your response. I tried that but its showing me this in the logs:  modified:   app (modified content, untracked content)
 modified:   build (modified content, untracked content)

Comment: It's normal Akanksha. It just means those files have not been added for commit. After git add app .. Execute git status and please tell me what response you getting.

Comment: I am getting this response after git add app,  git status,  modified:   app (modified content, untracked content)
 modified:   build (modified content, untracked content)

Comment: Commit your app folder changes by executing git commit . it should commit your files in app. If still the files are not getting committed. Then use git add on individual files and then commit, it will work .

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at **this documentation:** [link]https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Comment: Its showing me this error after i am adding individual files in 'app' folder      akankshas-MacBook-Pro:ListMe akankshajain$ git add app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml 
fatal: Pathspec 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' is in submodule 'app'

Comment: try removing and adding the directory by  **git rm --cached app** and then add again by **git add** and follow with commit and push

Comment: if git rm --cached app shows you this error: **fatal: not removing 'app' recursively without -r**
Then execute **git rm -rf --cached app** and rest follows as before

Comment: I tried this also but its not able to read and push the files and folders inside 'app' folder.

Comment: have you properly initialized your git ? Or is this the first time you committing for this particular git ? Check if your parent folder has .git folder and you haven't accidentally removed it.

Comment: Yes the .git folder is there

Comment: If you can afford losing your previous commits then I would suggest you to re initialize your git properly.                                                                                                                              **By first deleting your .git folder**, **Then git init**, **git remote add origin yourRepoUrl**, **git add allRequiredFIles**, **git commit**,                                                                                                     **git push -f origin master**.

Comment: I am suggesting this because I feel something is wrong with git initialization. Personally I encountered such errors when I accidentally messed up with .git folder .

Comment: Try using a different remote name if you re-initialize your git. I haven't tried it personally so am not sure but that might keep previous commits unaffected.

Comment: I just checked your actual Repository on gitHub and looking at your commits I can safely say that re-initializing your repository will be the best solution for you. *A little extra - You can avoid .idea/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Its showing me this error:

modified:   app (modified content, untracked content)
    modified:   build (modified content, untracked content)